# The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to set some properties on the virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, emulation

I've installed Windows phone 8 SDK successfully and I have run the applications successfully on the emulators. Everything was fine.

**Now I have updated my Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone Version 2 to Version 4.
And I have downloaded and installed the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 Update 3 Emulators. Now I run the application in Emulator WVGA 512MB and the application running successfully.
Now when I try to run the application in Emulator Update 3 1080P, then I am getting the below error.**

[image]

Please help me how to solve the above issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WP 8 Emulator works on a virtual machine, so you should check virtual machine settings on Hyper-V. It seems that Emulator needs more memory and your computer has not enough.

Comment: Could you please tell me how should I check the virtual machine settings.

Comment: You can check your virtual machine settings with Hyper-V manager, included with Windows 8. You have some examples [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/06/20/hyper-v-support-in-windows-8.aspx)

Comment: Yes I've checked and the start up memory is 512 MB. So I've changed it to 1024 MB. But still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @M.Kumaran above link not woking?